# Is there a character limit on each group_concated item in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am using group_concat to attach texts with some other text-info to some items. There are 5 texts belonging to an item and these texts can be quite large (up to 3000 chars).

Before I increased group_concat_max_len, it did cut of the group_concated texts at some point (e.g. text 1 and 2 were group_concated but text 3, 4 and 5 were not because of the group_concat_max_len limit being too low).

After I increased group_concat_max_len to 10MB (which is more than enough for my task), it does group_concat all five texts but if an individual text is too large (approx. > 1500 chars), it will cut the individual group_concated text (not the whole group). 
Meaning with a group_concat_max_len of 10MB, I could group_concat now even 50 texts with each of them having 1000 chars but if one of the texts had approx. more than 1500 chars, the chars of this individual one would be cut off.

Thus, my question is whether there is a limit on how large an individual group_concated text can be and how I can fix it?

------------------EDIT------------------------------

Thanks strawberry and solarfare for that hint - so group_concat is not the issue. I have know tested it with a small portion of the entire query while dumping the result immediately after the query. Also, I checked the table and the entire text is definately stored inside the table field. The problem with the text being cut-off still exists though once the row was fetched. I assume know it is something with the table-setup but I cant figure it out. Please see my query and the according table setups.

```
public function test(){
    $sql = "SELECT vi.*, "
    . "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT vis.info_en ORDER BY vis.priority 
       SEPARATOR '----') as settings FROM $this->table AS vi "
    . "LEFT JOIN vocab_items_settings vis ON vis.vocab_item_id = vi.id "
    . "WHERE vi.id = 281";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($row);
    exit;
    //text of the first group_concated item is the largest and gets cut-off after approx 1500 chars. I replaced it with other dummy-text but issue is still there. All further group_concated texts to the item do not exceed approx 1500 chars and thus do not get cut-off 
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: From my point of view, there is no problem in SQL for GROUP_CONCAT need form any part of the solution.

Comment: No, group_concat_max_len should do it. Make sure your data actually contains the long text (maybe your column is not big enough) or that there isn't some intermediate function that cuts the string. Could you add a reproducable example (create a table with just an id and a column with the same type as your original column), insert a long text, try your group by-code on it. If it actually shortens the string, post all 3 parts (the create table, the inserts, the group by). If it doesn't, check (or post) your original query to see if there is something that the query does that cuts your strings.

Comment: i realize that removing DISTINCT & ORDER BY causes the text to not be cut but then it gives me duplicated results and no order ... I dont get it ....

Comment: @MaxWidth I realize it's been a while but did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I've gone through hours of brain hurt to get down to the exact same problem and no apparent solution.  Been through all variables looking for a limit that matches; nothing.  All content is there and retrievable *except* in the group_concat where each part gets cut. Thanks for confirming it works without distinct and order - same here now - but like you say, it's not ideal.

Comment: @randomsock I never got to the bottom of this issue so I ended up removing the group_concat and instead used PHP to order the results after the query was fetched. I dont know whether you are even using PHP or whether the code will help you but I will post my code below in a second

Answer (score 0):

Since the user randomsock ran into the same issue, I am posting the result what I ended up doing. I never got to the bottom of this issue, so I ended up removing the `GROUP_CONCAT` part that included the large text portions and instead I did the array structuring with PHP after the query was fetched. in general I have since never used `GROUP_CONCAT` again unless dealing with small amount of data.

1. Instead of `GROUP_CONCAT`ing the data, I instead added them to the `SELECT` portion. This resulted now in multiple rows being fetched instead of 1 in which everything was group_concated inside.

vi = vocab_items

vis = vocab_item_settings (which includes large text portions)

```
$sql = "SELECT vi.*, vis.info_en, vis.name FROM $this->table AS vi "
. "LEFT JOIN vocab_items_settings vis ON vis.vocab_item_id = vi.id "
. "WHERE vi.id = 281";

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

2. Doing the structuring in PHP

a. I created an array with the data from vocab_items (vi) which is the same foreach row. Thus I used `rows[0]`.

```
$formatted_rows = array(
        'title' => $rows[0]['title'],
        'type' => $rows[0]['type'],
        .....
);
```

b. I pushed each vocab_item_settings (vis) into the `$formatted_rows` array. In my case, each vocab_item_settings actually had multiple texts. In such a scenario, I thus also had to prevent duplicates from being added to the `$formatted_rows['settings'][]` array as indicated with the three lines of code that I commented out (//)

```
// $valArr = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    //if (!in_array($row['name'], $valArr)) {
        $formatted_rows['settings'][] = array(
                'info' => $row['info_en'],
                .....
        )
        //array_push($valArr, $row['name']);
    }


}
```